# Why is there no dedicated type for filehandles?

Tags: perl

Hashes and scalars are in a different namespace.  So I can do this:

```
%foo = %bar
```

without concern about messing up the value of `%bar`.

Why doesn't the same logic apply to filehandles?  If I do this:

```
*FOO = *BAR
```

I've not only made `<FOO>` do the same thing as `<BAR>`, I've altered `$FOO`, `@FOO`, and `%FOO` as well.

Is it this way just because that's how Perl was first written, and it's entrenched?  Because there aren't any more non-alphanumeric prefix characters left?  Or is there a reason it *has* to work this way?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  With lexical filehandles, IO::Handle, and *thingy{IO} notation, there's probably more than one _better_ way to do what you want.

Comment: There were only so many ASCII punctuation characters available for use as [sigils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)).

Comment: @keith Seriously?  I suspected this may be the reason.  Maybe unicode sigils are the way of the future.

Comment: Yes, seriously (though I'm only speculating). Unicode sigils might be a good idea as soon as I can count on having a `¿` key on every keyboard I'll ever use to edit code.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, I strongly doubt it has anything to do with the limited number of punctuation characters available, since I don't see why it would even have been considered. Storing them in scalars makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, You just need to be able to bind a key to a macro that generates the symbol, which any half-decent code editor can do. But yeah, it's not gonna happen for that reason. There was suggestion for `qq` and the like to recognize outside-of-ASCII braces as paired delimiters, which would be acceptable since you wouldn't be forced to use them; you could still use `qq{}`.

Comment: @ikegami It does make sense, but by the same reasoning, would it make sense to store hashes, arrays, and subroutines in scalars too?  I know you _can_, but you don't _have_ to.

Comment: @Keight Thompson, Of course you don't have to use a scalar. It just doesn't make sense not to. There's no compelling reason to allow scalars and file handles with the same name to exist at the same time.

Comment: @Keight Thompson, Arrays and hashes predate lexicals. They come from a time where everything was in the symbol table (i.e. globs). Now that we have lexicals, it doesn't make sense to rely on the symbol table since variables therein are global.

Comment: @Keight Thompson, And there's also the fact that we'd still need to differentiate scalar foo ($foo) from elements of array foo (@foo) from array referenced by scalar foo (@$foo) from element of array foo ($foo[$i]) from slice of array foo (@foo[$i]), so we'd end up with the same or similar syntax even if the array was stored in a scalar. (btw, an array actually is a type of scalar internally.)

Comment: Voting to close as not constructive (and submitting the comment trail here as evidence).  The OP wants an authoritative historical — or pat anthropological or gotcha-surprise technical — answer for why this aspect of the language's design isn't as he would have expected.  That kind of answer is not forthcoming.

Comment: Oops, I misaddress my comments. They were for gcbenison.

Comment: @ikegami: If you mispell my name, I don't get a notification. Sure, storing file handles and directory handles in scalars makes sense, but old versions of Perl didn't do that, they just used barewords.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, doh! But like I said, they were for gcbenison anyway. I was disputing his claim that it makes sense to create a sigil for file handles because array and hashes have their own sigil.

Comment: @ikegami: I'd say it would have made more sense to have special sigils for file and directory handles than to use barewords, as Perl 4 did. In modern code, we can use scalars, of course -- but sometimes dealing with predefined filehandles like `STDIN` and friends can be annoying.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, Strawman. False dichotomy. Noone said barewords would be better.

Comment: @ikegami: I'm speculating about the historical reasons. In Perl 4, barewords were all we had. I suspect (with no evidence) that filehandles would have been given their own sigil if there had been a reasonable ASCII punctuation character to use for them -- and in Perl 5 `open $FOO, '<', foo.txt` might give you an actual filehandle reference rather than a `GLOB` reference.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, Reasons for what? Using a type glob? Everything used type globs since lexicals didn't exist yet. For being forced to reference file handles indirectly? Don't know, but I don't by this ASCII limitation. File handles have been in the language since day one, so they were intentionally designed that way, not because a resource ran out when they tried to add file handles to the language.

Comment: @ikegami: Reasons that Larry Wall, when he was originally designing Perl, chose to use sigils for scalars, arrays, hashes, and subroutines, but not for handles. It's entirely possible that my speculation is wrong. It's also possible that Larry has specifically addressed the issue (I haven't bothered to check). In the admittedly uncertain event that I'm right, it could be the answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 7):

> Why doesn't the same logic apply to filehandles?

First of all `*BAR` is not a file handle; it's a glob. "Glob" is short for "type glob" or "typeglob". Globs are what the symbol table is made of.

As you've stated, `*FOO = *BAR;` does copy the glob just as `%foo = %bar;` copies the hash. So the same logic does apply to <s>filehandles</s> globs.

There's no way to specifically refer to a file handle in Perl. It's always done indirectly through a glob, reference, or reference to a glob.

If you wanted to copy the file handle from one glob to another, you could use the following:

```
 *FOO = *BAR{IO};
```

A glob (e.g. `*FOO`) is an associative array like a hash, with a fixed set of keys including `SCALAR`, `ARRAY`, ... and `IO`. Assigning a reference to a glob (such as the one returned by `*BAR{IO}`) will assign the reference to the proper slot of the glob automatically.

But why are you messing with globs? Would you do

```
*foo = \$bar;
```

or

```
*foo = *bar{SCALAR};
```

to copy a string? No, so why would you do that to copy a file handle. Like for strings, you should be using

```
 $foo = $bar;
```

The underlying reason you're having difficulty is because you're using technology obsoleted 13 years (6 major versions) ago. You shouldn't be using globals; you should be using properly-scoped lexicals.

```
 open(my $BAR, ...) or die $!;
 my $FOO = $BAR;
```

or

```
 my $FOO = \*STDOUT;
```

Then use `$FOO` as you would use `FOO`.

```
while (<FOO>)    =>   while (<$FOO>)
print FOO ...;   =>   print $FOO ...;
func(\*FOO);     =>   func($FOO);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Could I write a whole program never using `$` by always using `*FOO{SCALAR}`?

Comment: no, because that gets you a scalar reference, which is hard to actually use without `$`.  however, there is http://p3rl.org/variable (but don't use that :) )

Comment: That gets you a reference, so you'd have to use `${ *FOO{SCALAR} }`, which reintroduces the `$`. It also means you'd only be using package variables -- not lexicals -- so you'd have to start using `local` everywhere, but `local ${ *FOO{SCALAR} }` doesn't work.

Comment: Adjusted the post to more clearly answer the actual question asked.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can do this:

```
*FOO = *BAR{IO}
```

but, honestly, the use of bareword filehandles (ones that look like FOO) is best left behind. Its a historical artifact, made obsolete with Perl 5.6 (many years ago). Instead, you should put filehandles in scalars:

```
open my $foo, '<', 'filename';
my $line = <$foo>;
# ⋮
```

And then, of course, you can copy them like any other scalar `$bar = $foo`.

Also, you generally want to avoid two variables with the same name, as it can get confusing.

```
my @a = (1, 2, 3);
my $a = 4;
my %a = (5 => 6, 7 => 8);

say $a, $a[0], $a{5}; # the scalar, the array, the hash (in that order)
say @a{5,7};          # the hash
```

Comment: note that IO has both the filehandle and dirhandle (unfortunately)

Comment: @ysth Yep. And if you've got an identically named filehandle and dirhandle (is that even possible?) you deserve what you get.

Comment: yes, it is possible and they work completely independently, except that `*FOO{IO}` gets both

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation under Perldata (see the Typeglobs and Filehandles  section). The first part reads:

Perl uses an internal type called a typeglob to hold an entire symbol table entry. The type prefix of a typeglob is a *, because it represents all types. This used to be the preferred way to pass arrays and hashes by reference into a function, but now that we have real references, this is seldom needed.

Ken

Comment: I understand that `*FOO` is a typeglob; what I'm wondering is why it's necessary to be concerned with typeglobs or references when dealing with filehandles but not with, say, hashes or strings.

Comment: you don't exactly have to be concerned with them; just use a scalar variable; underneath it will be a reference to file/dir handle, but you don't need to do anything special because of that.

Comment: If you know *FOO is a typeglob, why would you not expect it to alter all three of the types associated with it (scalar, hash, array)?

Comment: @ken I do expect it.  I'm trying to understand why the language is designed that way.